# Which Phase is Ant-Man in?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

Marvel has been splitting their Cinematic Universe into 'Phases' which roughly correspond to roughly 4 years of films, capped with an *Avengers* film.  *Ant-Man* resides in an odd place, being announced long before the movies in Phase 3, and being released months after *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

So which Phase is *Ant-Man* in?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the Phase 3 announcement event, Marvel's Kevin Feige had a Q&A session.  [During which](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ak_2fhZUe0s#t=501) he said this:

> **Audience member** - Phase 3 seems just enormous, and we're used to 4-5 movies in each Phase.  Can you talk about your plan moving forward how many movies you're planning on putting movies in each Phase?
>
> **Kevin Feige** - I don't think we set out to say any particular number.  Phase 1 was 6 films.  Phase 2, and for those following along, you will realize, that ***Ant-Man* truly is the end of Phase 2, and *Civil War* is truly the beginning of Phase 3.**  So that leaves us with 6 films in Phase 2, and 9 films in Phase 3.

Comment: Is there any in-universe significance to the phases, or are they purely out of universe thing?

Comment: @DVK Purely out of universe book-keeping.  Like referring to the two *Star Wars* trilogies as the Original vs Prequel Trilogies.  I guess there's in universe significance in that a group of Avengers tends to team up at the end of one, which suggests a large existential threat to Earth.  But one of the biggest shifts in the universe came from *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, so I dunno that we have enough data to really infer trends.

Comment: Woah. They're going to do a Civil War movie?

Comment: @SystemDown Yeah, they announced all of Phase 3 a little while back.  Scroll down in the list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Films

Comment: @System Down: The future of superhero movies, in terms of what’s been announced, is terrifying. 2015 may, in the future, be looked back on fondly as a nice quiet year with just Avengers 2, Ant-Man, and the Fantastic Four reboot. If everything comes out as announced, 2016 and 2017 will have seven superhero movies *each*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yeah... it's glorious.